# MongoDB and Write/Read Consistency

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've passed a MongoU Course and Midway through a second. I've read what I can and done what I can to learn, but failed to learn how to handle what I consider a standard situation.

Consider a booking system for Hotel Rooms. There is a collection bookings:

4/1 - Room 1
4/1 - Room 2
4/1 - Room 3

Then when a client checks the bookings collections { date: 4/1 Room: 3}, they will find a booking and the application can deny the booking.

However, say two users look for { date: 4/1 Room: 4} at the same time, the application will proceed with booking for both clients, meaning they will try to create the booking.

What happens next? One of the clients get a booking and the other fails. Somewhat of a race condition? Or does one client get a booking and other person overwrites it.

Can this be prevented with a write concern? Or some other lock? Or is this a better case for more atomic database?

All the demos I see have to do with a blog, which have very little concerns for unique data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you need to be careful with your data models and – of course – your application flow.

One way to prevent duplicate bookings would be to use a compound `_id` field:

```
{
  _id: { room: 1, date:"4/1" }
}
```

So once room 1 is booked for 4/1, there is no way a duplicate booking for room 1 can be created, as `_id's` are guaranteed to be unique. The second **`insert`** will fail. Alternatively, you can create a unique index on an arbitrary compound field.

Be aware though that your application should not upserts or updates on this document without proper permission checks, which does not apply to MongoDB only. In the most simple case, for updates, you would need to check wether the user trying to update the document actually is the user who booked the room. So our model needs to be expanded:

```
{
  _id:{room:"1",date:"4/1"},
  reservationFor:"userID"
}
```

So now it becomes pretty easy: before inserting a reservation, you check for one. If the result is not empty, there already is a reservation for that room. If an exception is thrown because of a duplicate ID on insert, there was a reservation made in the meantime. Before doing an update, you need to check wether `reservationFor` holds the userID of the current user.

How to react to this kind of situation heavily depends on the language and framework(s) used to develop your application. What I tend to do is to catch the according exceptions and modify an `errorMessage` accordingly.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. I think you are right.

It's funny that the solution of the unique compound _id came to me just the other day, thinking that would be a way to guarantee that it was unique. 

Appreciate your thoughtful answer. Take care.